# Host securely other people on apache2

Tags: linux, security, apache2, virtualhost

For the context : I'm a student and I must do a project with some other people of my class. My role is to prepare them a web server that each one can use and access from anywhere. I plan to host everything on a dedicated server that I already have to avoid additional cost and give to each people a subdomain that will be redirected with VirtualHosts. They will be able to send files to the server with a SFTP server (openssh), they will get an account per person and it will be chrooted to their virtualhost directory.

My main problem : Will this be secure ? I mean, if one of the user set an easy password or just do anything risky, can someone access the other's people virtualhost or even the host dedicated machine ? I already thought about .htaccess and they will be deactivated. Is there another way to get out of an apache virtualhost ?

Things to note : they will have apache, php and an access to a mysql (or maybe mariadb, I don't know for now) database. So, they may be able to upload some old, unsecure code. Some of these users are not very educated to cybersecurity.

The server is a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks for the advices,

Answer (score 0):

If you limit their access to only their own home directory, that's a good start.

A good layer of security would also be to implement 2FA, check out Duo Mobile, you can implement it for SSH logins (or need more details, eg. what options do they have to login into the server?)

If the users are not very educated in cybersecurity as you mentioned, it will be difficult for them to escape the virtual host they have access to.

Although i need more details such as each virtual host will have a separate database or it will be talking to a central database? also, for a paranoid measure, consider where the server is hosted. There are lots of variables that can be affirmed from what you described, but it is best to keep the server on its own network with nothing critical in the same subnet. Just in case.

Comment: 2FA is a good idea, and I already use Duo Mobile for work. The users are not very educated, but I would not be surprised if one of them would try to access to the code of the other to copy their code, you know, if they can avoid to work some hours, they will do. And for the database, they will be on the same mysql server and have one database per student.
Thanks for your help